# Get all accounts and sort by balance

Tags: horizon

How can I get all accounts and sort by the balance?  I'd like to build a list of all accounts and then sort them by the balance.  I realize the data set would be large, but was thinking maybe via a cursor I could create some paging.

Answer (score 2):

I think for this use case is best to run your own Horizon and Stellar Core instances so that you have direct access to their database.

Stellar Foundation provides a [docker image](https://github.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core-horizon) to help you get started running Stellar Core and Horizon.
After you finished syncing, you [can access the databases directly](https://github.com/stellar/docker-stellar-core-horizon#accessing-databases).

In your case, you want to access the `core` database, for example using the `psql` command:

```
psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U stellar core
```

The `core` database contains the `accounts` table with the following schema:

```
+--------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
| Column             | Type                  | Modifiers   |
|--------------------+-----------------------+-------------|
| accountid          | character varying(56) |  not null   |
| balance            | bigint                |  not null   |
| seqnum             | bigint                |  not null   |
| numsubentries      | integer               |  not null   |
| inflationdest      | character varying(56) |             |
| homedomain         | character varying(32) |  not null   |
| thresholds         | text                  |  not null   |
| flags              | integer               |  not null   |
| lastmodified       | integer               |  not null   |
| buyingliabilities  | bigint                |             |
| sellingliabilities | bigint                |             |
+--------------------+-----------------------+-------------+
```

The query you are looking for is something similar to:

```
select * from accounts order by balance limit 100;
```